# The wording about instantiation of a pack expansion in [temp.variadic]

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

I wonder Is it a mis-wording in the following quote, that is

[temp.variadic#7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.variadic#7)

> The instantiation of a pack expansion that is neither a sizeof... expression nor a fold-expression produces a list E1,E2,...En
> , where N is the number of elements in the pack expansion parameters. Each **Ei is generated by instantiating the pattern** and replacing each pack expansion parameter with its ith element. Such an element, in the context of the instantiation, is interpreted as follows:
>
> > - if the pack is a template parameter pack, the element is a template parameter of the corresponding kind (type or non-type) designating the type or value from the template argument; otherwise,
> > - if the pack is a function parameter pack, the element is an **id-expression** designating the function parameter that resulted from the instantiation of the pattern where the pack is declared.

The pattern of a function parameter pack is a parameter-declaration without ellipsis because it's defined as the following:
[temp.variadic#4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.variadic#4)

> A pack expansion consists of a pattern and an ellipsis, the instantiation of which produces zero or more instantiations of the pattern in a list (described below). The form of the pattern depends on the context in which the expansion occurs. Pack expansions can occur in the following contexts:
>
> > - [...]
> > - In a function parameter pack ([dcl.fct]); the pattern is the **parameter-declaration** without the ellipsis.

A usual parameter-declaration consists of :

- attribute-specifier-seq (opt)  decl-specifier-seq declarator
- attribute-specifier-seq (opt) decl-specifier-seq declarator = initializer-clause
- attribute-specifier-seq (opt) decl-specifier-seq abstract-declarator(opt)
- attribute-specifier-seq (opt) decl-specifier-seq abstract-declarator (opt) = initializer-clause

In any case , the `decl-specifier-seq` is not an optional component.

#### In this example

```cpp
template<typename...T>
void func(T...args){
}
```

`T...args` is a function parameter pack, thereof, `T args` is its pattern. So my issues is, why the element generated from instantiation of a pattern of a function parameter pack is `id-expression`, However the `id-expression` is only a part of declarator of a parameter-declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to answer this question, To understand these sentences, These sentences are necessary to split to several portions.

> 1. A **function parameter pack** is a function parameter that accepts zero or more function arguments.

What is a function parameter pack?

In c++17 standard, it says:

[dcl.fct#16](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct#16)

> A declarator-id or abstract-declarator containing an ellipsis shall only be used in a parameter-declaration. Such a parameter-declaration is a parameter pack. When it is part of a parameter-declaration-clause, the parameter pack is a function parameter pack.

It sounds like a parameter-declaration where declarator-id or abstract-declarator containing an ellipsis and  such a parameter-declaration appears in parameter-declaration-clause, such a parameter-declaration is a function parameter pack. Right?

Now, we see what the latest draft says:

[dcl.fct#21](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#21)

> A declarator-id or abstract-declarator containing an ellipsis shall only be used in a parameter-declaration. When it is part of a parameter-declaration-clause, the parameter-declaration declares a function parameter pack.

It says a parameter-declaration where declarator-id or abstract-declarator containing an ellipsis and  such a parameter-declaration appears in parameter-declaration-clause, as far as here, they are the same, however, the difference is here, such parameter-declaration **declares a function parameter pack**. It means `T...args` declares a function parameter pack.

> 2. A pack expansion consists of a pattern and an ellipsis, the instantiation of which produces zero or more instantiations of the pattern in a list... **Pack expansions** can **occur** in the following contexts:
>
> > - **In a function parameter pack** ([dcl.fct]); the pattern is the parameter-declaration without the ellipsis.

The sentence means a pack expansion occurred in a context that is a function parameter pack, the pattern is the parameter-declaration without the ellipsis. Informally, for this case `T...args`, thereof `T...` denotes a pack expansion and the pattern of `T...args` is `T args`.

> The instantiation of a pack expansion...
>
> > 3. if the pack is a function parameter pack, the element is an id-expression designating the function parameter that resulted from **the instantiation of the pattern where the pack is declared**.

About the third bullet, this pack doesn't denote `T`, it is a stuff declared by a parameter-declaration as the analysis of the first bullet.    Another important point to understand this sentence is **function parameter that resulted from the instantiation of the pattern where the pack is declared**, As the aforementioned, the pattern is `T args` where the pack is declared. So, the emphasized sentence means `function parameter` is the result from these instantiations of pattern `T args` of pack expansion `T...args`, Now it confirms to the second bullet, and for some case like `postfix-expression(args...)`, The pack `args` is used to be a pattern of such pack expansion and the instantiation of such pack expansion would be the `id-expression` designating the function parameter which from the instantiation of the pattern `T args`.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I have reread the standard carefully and write the understanding in this answers.

Comment: _args is a function parameter pack due to args is a function parameter_ Why `args` and not `...args` or `T...args` is a function parameter? In `func(T...)`, there is no parameter?

Comment: _implies the parameter is an entity_ Do you think this explains why `args` and not `T...args` is parameter?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I have updated my answers, there're some difference between c++17 and the latest draft, and the latest draft can interpret why `args` is.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Informally.  `T args` is a parameter-declaration, such declaration declares a parameter, namely `args`.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer In this case `func(T...)`, it's also a pack expansion, however such parameter-declaration declares nothing. Hence there's no named pack can be used in some contexts.

Comment: So, in case of `func(T...)`, there is no parameter, so there is no function parameter pack, so you can't pass multiple arguments to such function (template)?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer No, func(T...) indeed a parameter-declaration, however it declares nothing, because your example is the case `attribute-specifier-seq<opt> decl-specifier-seq abstract-declarator<opt>` in parameter-declaration tree, thereof `abstract-declarator` denote `...` as said in [dcl.name#nt:noptr-abstract-pack-declarator](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.name#nt:noptr-abstract-pack-declarator), and according to A parameter pack whose **name** appears within the pattern of a pack expansion is expanded by that pack expansion., there's no name be declared in such...

Comment: @LanguageLawyer In such parameter-declaration, so such a function parameter pack can't be used in other context.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer As a case you reminder me. Another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62649169/is-it-a-defect-about-deducing-template-arguments-for-function-parameter-pack) about temp. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In that pack expansion, `T` **and** `args` are expanded (even as the latter is being *declared* as a pack); as such, the resulting *parameter-declaration*s have the form `T1 args1,T2 args2,…` and are properly equipped with a `decl-specifier`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216952/discussion-on-answer-by-davis-herring-the-wording-about-instantiation-of-a-pack).