# Is it a defect about deducing template arguments for function parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, language-lawyer

```cpp
template<typename...T>
void func(T...args){
}
int main(){
  func(1,2.0,'c');
}
```

Consider the above code, there's a rule that applied to it to deduce these template arguments for this function template (call). It is:
[temp.deduct.call#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.call#1)

> For a function parameter pack that occurs at the end of the parameter-declaration-list, deduction is performed for each remaining argument of the call, taking the type P of the **declarator-id** of the function parameter pack as the corresponding function template parameter type. Each deduction deduces template arguments for subsequent positions in the template parameter packs expanded by the function parameter pack.

That means for the parameter-declaration `T...args`, it declares a function template park, hence the function parameter type that is used to against the type of function argument is `T` because `...args` is the declarator-id of this declaration. So, for this function call `func(1,2.0,'c')`, template parameter pack T would be the set consists of  `{int,double,char}`.

However, consider the following variant:

```
template<typename...T>
void func(T...){
}
int main(){
  func(1,2.0,'c');
}
```

There's no declarator-id here, just an abstract-declarator that denote the `...`, How would the quote be applied to this case? What's the corresponding function parameter type here? How to form this parameter type? Is it a defect for this case when draft the standard?

Comment: I think you can file an issue on github

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Have done it.

Answer (score 0):

In [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) it explains:

> Function parameter list
>
> In a function parameter list, if an ellipsis appears in a parameter declaration (whether it names a function parameter pack (as in, Args ... args) or not) the parameter declaration is the pattern:

```
template<typename ...Ts> void f(Ts...) {}
f('a', 1);  // Ts... expands to void f(char, int)
f(0.1);     // Ts... expands to void f(double)
```

Comment: Yes, I think , For a function parameter pack, Take type P of the parameter-declaration which remove ellipsis as the function parameter type and  such P is used to participate with template arguments deducing.